# Calculator, clear window when second variable is typed after chosen operator

Tags: c#, class, operators, calculator

So I have this calculator http://gyazo.com/589156935eec141c3aedf83b9f960d29 (not enough reputation sorry)

When I type [1] and then [2] the display shows [12]

If I press a operator for example [+] the number 12 is still supposed to be shown in the display.

But, if I now start typing new numbers The old ones are supposed to be removed from the display. But i can't get this to work.

My form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Miniräknare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Miniräknare miniräknare;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            miniräknare = new Miniräknare(0, 0, "", 0, false);
        }

        private void btnEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.doEquals();
        }

        private void btnNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("1", tbxWindow.Text);             
        }

        private void btnNum2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("2", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("3", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("4", tbxWindow.Text);

        }

        private void btnNum5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("5", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("6", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("7", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("8", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("9", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnNum0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (tbxWindow.Text != "") tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand("0", tbxWindow.Text);

        }

        private void btnOperatorDivision_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnOperatorTimes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnOperatorPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            miniräknare.Op = "+";




        }

        private void btnOperatorMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            miniräknare.Op = "-";
            miniräknare.Change = true;
        }        

        private void btnDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand(",", tbxWindow.Text);
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnCos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnTan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSquared_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnModulus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExponential_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnlogarithm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn1OverX_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnLn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnPi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnMemoryClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnMemoryRecall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnMemorySave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }        
    }
}
```

My class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Miniräknare
{
    class Miniräknare
    {
        private double first;
        private double second;
        private string op; 
        private double memory; 
        private bool change;

        public Miniräknare(double first, double second, string op, double memory, bool change)
        {
            this.first = 0;
            this.second = 0;
            this.op = "";
            this.memory = 0;
            this.change = false;
        }

        public double First
        {
            get {return first; }
            set { first = value; }
        }

        public double Second
        {
            get { return second; }
            set { second = value; }
        }

        public string Op
        {
            get { return op; }
            set { op = value; }
        }

        public double Memory
        {
            get { return memory; }
            set { memory = value; }
        }

        public bool Change
        {
            get { return change; }
            set { change = value; }
        }

        public string getOperand(string t, string textBox)
        {
            textBox = textBox + t;
            if (t.Equals(","))
            {
                change = true;
                second = double.Parse(textBox);
            }
            else if (op.Equals(""))
            {
                if (!change)
                {
                    textBox = "";
                    change = true;
                    textBox = textBox + t;
                }
                first = double.Parse(textBox);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!change)
                {
                    textBox = "";
                    change = true;
                    textBox = textBox + t;
                }
                second = double.Parse(textBox);
            }
            return textBox;
        }

       /* public string calculateAnswer()
        {


        } */

        public string doEquals()
        {
            if (op == "-" ) return (first - second).ToString();





            else return null;



        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Remove all of your empty event handlers from the question. 2. Learn to use the debugger and step through code.

Comment: 3. Use automatic properties instead of fields (this is just a style issue but improves the readability of your code).

Comment: Reputation or no reputation, please do not use links to external resources to document your question. A StackOverflow question should be entirely self-contained, as links to other pages (even those within StackOverflow) may change or even disappear, rendering them irrelevant to the question you posted. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on why and how to provide a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example that clearly illustrates your question.

Comment: Another design recommendation: Instead of having all the code you have atm, use the Tag property of the buttons, link them all to the same event handler and call `tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand(((Button)sender).Tag as String, tbxWindow.Text);`

Comment: Additionally, your constructor takes parameters as input, but you don't assign the input parameters to your class's variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following block after pressing "+" button "change" is true and the block is skipped when type the first digit of the second number.

```
    else
    {
        if (!change)
        {
            textBox = "";
            change = true;
            textBox = textBox + t;
        }
        second = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
```

since you assigned textBox at the beginning of the getOperand method, it will return the value combining what you already had on the screen with the new char.

```
public string getOperand(string t, string textBox)
{
    textBox = textBox + t;
```

This should do the trick:

```
public string getOperand(string t, string textBox)
{


    if (t.Equals(","))
    {
        textBox = textBox + t;
        change = true;
        second = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
    else if (Op.Equals(""))
    {
        textBox = textBox + t;
        if (!change)
        {
            textBox = "";
            change = true;
            textBox = textBox + t;
        }
        first = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!change)
        {
            textBox = textBox + t;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox = t;
            change = false;
        }
        second = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
    return textBox;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, almost :/ If I want to enter longer inputs in the second number with more than one char it automaticly erases the old one ( pretty obvious).

Comment: Add `change = false;` in the `else` code-block to allow for additional input

Comment: @AzeyZ - one problem at a time

Comment: @AlexG Thanks for your time, but unforuneatly I actually already got that code ^^. Well one of the problems had to do with another part of the code which I have fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and this does not answer the question asked (which has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29258926/3864353)) and might be marked as off-topic, but wanted to show the changes as suggested in the various comments in an orderly fashion, just to help you improve your coding (current and future) experience.

Changes that can be made to your `Miniräknare` class (Comments added to explain):

```
public class Miniräknare
{
  public Miniräknare()
  {
    // Have a default constructor that sets all the default properties
    First = 0;
    Second = 0;
    Op = "";
    Memory = 0;
    Change = false;
  }

  public Miniräknare(double first, double second, string op, double memory, bool change)
  {
    // If you have a constructor with parameters, use the parameters to set your properties
    First = first;
    Second = second;
    Op = op;
    Memory = memory;
    Change = change;
  }

  // Use automatic properties, this improves readability and less confusion (As per D Stanley in comments)
  public double First { get; set; }
  public double Second { get; set; }
  public string Op { get; set; }
  public double Memory { get; set; }
  public bool Change { get; set; }

  public string getOperand(string t, string textBox)
  {
    // Apply changes as per the accepted answer
    textBox = textBox + t;
    if (t.Equals(","))
    {
      Change = true;
      Second = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
    else if (Op.Equals(""))
    {
      if (!Change)
      {
        textBox = "";
        Change = true;
        textBox = textBox + t;
      }
      First = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
    else
    {
      if (!Change)
      {
        textBox = "";
        Change = true;
        textBox = textBox + t;
      }
      Second = double.Parse(textBox);
    }
    return textBox;
  }

  public string doEquals()
  {
    if (Op == "-") return (First - Second).ToString();
    else return null;
  }
}
```

Changes in your `Form1`:

Instantiate your `miniräknare` variable now like this, since you where setting them to the defaults with your original input parameters.

```
miniräknare = new Miniräknare();
```

Replace all your `btnNum1_Click` to `btnNum9_Click` event handlers with this single event handler to improve readability and volume of your code (Check additional comments in the code):

```
private void btnNumber_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // !! Remember !! to set the Tag value of each of your buttons to their corresponding values
  // Then change btnNum1 to btnNum9's Click events to btnNumber_Click
  // Additionally you can also just use ((Button)sender).Text if their text values will never change
  // You could even do this with your operators, unless you have specific code for the button (like you have for btnNum0)
  tbxWindow.Text = miniräknare.getOperand(((Button)sender).Tag as String, tbxWindow.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I realised this will not work If i whish to enter longer numbers like 113 in the second number after I have clicked a operator. Now it will not accept numbers with more than one char.

Comment: Forgot to add you on the other comment so will do so here: Problem Solved ^^